# How to set a permissions on Opportunities in salesforce to see own created opportunity not other user opportunities

Tags: salesforce

The problem is when i login to salesforce and go to opportunities i saw my own opportunities
as well as other opportunities too that not created by me.

please help how can i set the permision on opportunities so that user can see there own opportunity rather than others.

Comment: also Is it possible that suppose there is one user "admin" who created a new user and  then admin uable to see the new user opportunity. as it haapen in my case admin saw the other user oportunitites created by them.
as i already redefine the organisation-wide default setting on Opportunity records to Private.

Answer (score 0):

If the sharing model is private, there are a few potential reasons that you could see other users' opportunities. If you have a System Administrator profile, if you have the 'Modify All Data' or 'View All Data' profile permissions, or if you have 'Modify All' or 'View All' permissions on the opportunity object, you will be able to see all the opportunities in an org. You will also be able to see opportunities of users that are below you in the role hierarchy, as well as any opportunities that are shared to you via sharing rules. Finally, you will also be able to see any opportunities that belong to accounts that you own, even if you do not own the opportunities themselves.